# Advise on script to remove files

Tags: file, powershell, delete-file

We have a backup program called Shadow protect.
We backup to a NAS then we replicate to a USB for off site protection.

We have a script that can detect the backup Chain we need to keep on the USB for a restore however we have no way or removing unneeded files to free up the space.

So is there a way of combining our script that detect the chain and removes any OTHER files no longer needed on the USB?

Example of the script and the output:
so even thought there are 415 files in the backup folder only the below are needed for a full restore.

```
image.exe qp Q:\ts01\C_VOL-b001-i676.spi "d=$n"
"C_VOL-b001.spf"
"C_VOL-b001-i283-cd-cm.spi"
"C_VOL-b001-i426-cd-cw.spi"
"C_VOL-b001-i593-cd-cw.spi"
"C_VOL-b001-i617-cd.spi"
"C_VOL-b001-i641-cd.spi"
"C_VOL-b001-i665-cd.spi"
"C_VOL-b001-i666.spi"
"C_VOL-b001-i667.spi"
"C_VOL-b001-i668.spi"
"C_VOL-b001-i669.spi"
"C_VOL-b001-i670.spi"
"C_VOL-b001-i671.spi"
"C_VOL-b001-i672.spi"
"C_VOL-b001-i673.spi"
"C_VOL-b001-i674.spi"
"C_VOL-b001-i675.spi"
"C_VOL-b001-i676.spi"
```

Hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

With the information you provided, why not set a variable with the known files you want then exclude them, like so:

```
$Exclude = @( "file1.foo", "file2.foo".....etc )
Remove-Item -Path "Q:\ts01\" -Exclude $Exclude -Force -Recurse
```

Not sure if this is what you mean :S